# In groovy how to pass on workspace path as file to XmlTestRunListener setReportDir?

Tags: file, groovy, xml-parsing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Goal of the project: I am trying to use the XmlTestRunListener and InstrumentationResultParser to parse the adb am instrument -r log to get xml on the jenkins node. I am using the class InstrumentationResultParser and XmlTestRunListener to get that done.

Issue: The XmlTestRunListener needs to setReport Dir which takes in file as a parameter.
Now, the am instrument log is on the jenkins agent node and if I try to pass on the filePath, it is getting referred to master. How do I create a file pointer for the path on the node.

eg code:
(I need to pass on the current workspace node as file, the current is giving me a pointer to my jenkins controller, whereas I need to get the path on the agent! )

```
def outputXmlDir = new File ("/opt/myworkspace") 
def listener = new XmlTestRunListener()
listener.setReportDir(outputXmlDir)
def parser = new InstrumentationResultParser("", listener)
parser.processNewLines("instrument.log")
parser.done()
```

Link to XmlTestRunListener (https://javadoc.io/static/com.android.tools.ddms/ddmlib/25.2.0/com/android/ddmlib/testrunner/XmlTestRunListener.html)

Would really appreciate, if I get some pointers on how to pass on the workspace path as file to setReportDir!
Thank you,
Kartik

Tried to do type cast of the string path as file. Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround.

So since my pipeline code was on jenkins and it executes on the master / controller, any reference to file system was referring to the one on controller.

So, I created a groovy script dynamically on the agent and accessed the agent's file system.